# How to apply opacity only for mat-card, but not for the rest of the content inside mat-card?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a few mat-card which are flexbox items. I want a card itself to be a little transparent `opacity: 0.8;`. But the rest elements inside stay as they are.

So inside all other items I've put `opacity: 1;`, but that didn't help.

```
.mat-card {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give .mat-card a background color of rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) instead of using opacity (or whichever colour you want for the background color):

```
.mat-card{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is simple yet effective way.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `opacity` property to a parent element then all of the child elements within this will reflect with it's parent `opacity` property and you can't override this to child element. So if you need background color `opacity` to a parent element then remove `opacity` property from parent element, and add `rgba` color property within this.

```
.mat-card {background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're using multiple elements, its always good to keep separate properties for elements which you derived child elements from. In this case **opacity** ends up becoming a part of all the elements hence its better to use **background-color** property.